# Unable to access API created on flask server running on docker container

Tags: docker, flask, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm trying to create a GET API endpoint in python flask and run the flask in Docker container but I'm unable to access the API running inside the container. I tried looking on other answers but nothing worked.

server.py

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5000, debug=True)
```

Dockerfile

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM python:3.10.4

WORKDIR /code

ENV FLASK_APP=server.py
ENV FLASK_RUN_HOST=0.0.0.0
ENV FLASK_DEBUG="true"

EXPOSE 5000

RUN pip install --upgrade pip

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

# CMD ["python","server.py"]
CMD ["flask", "run", "--host", "0.0.0.0"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  flask-server:
    build: ./flask-server/
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    restart: on-failure
```

[image: Running server]

[image: Calling the Get API]

Comment: You're getting a 404 error. That suggests that you are able to successfully contact your Flask server, but you don't have a `/api/queue` endpoint.

Comment: I found the problem, the problem is since I am on an internal network I am not able to access the same end point on my localhost but if I try to request from a remote machine, I get the response. What can be the possible reason?